# Nested `ifelse` statements in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, for-loop, nested

I have data in the following format and am trying to create a new variable that includes the total number of deaths for each observation, where "present" indicates an ongoing event:

```
    Birth1  Death1  Birth2  Death2  Birth3  Death3  Birth4  Death4  Birth5  Death5  Birth6  Death6
  1 1990    present                                     
  2 1984    1986    1986    present                             
  3 1985    1988    1988    present                             
  4 1987    1991    1991    1994    1996    present                     
  5 1987    1989    1989    present
```

I tried `data$num.deaths <- ifelse(data$death1=="present", 0, 1)` but obviously that doesn't get at the observations that have more than one death event. I also tried nested ifelse but got the same result. Can anybody point me to a fast and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: can you `dput` your data, or at least the `head` of your data.

Comment: Please use `dput` to share your data. It's not if your data is a matrix or a data frame, what class it is, etc.

Comment: Are the empty space in your data (for example, observation A and Birth 2) NA? If you have missing values in a data column, you can not directly use logical functions in the `ifelse`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico @Conta @Gregor it's a pretty massive `.csv` file and the blanks in the above data are whitespace, not NAs.

Comment: So don't share the whole thing! Do something like `dput(droplevels(data[1:6, 1:6]))` but pick some rows and columns that illustrate the problem.

Comment: What is the problem with `dput()`?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Here it is.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. I think I'll mess with it some more on my own.

Comment: Now there is no sample output and the result of `dput(data)` is missing.  The purpose of SO is not just to answer the posters' questions but also to create a record of questions and answers for future reference.  I suggest you (1) either copy the Note at the end of my answer to your question or else simply refer to it and (2) show the expected output in your question, namely 0, 1, 1, 2.

Answer (score 3):

Extract the columns that represent deaths giving `Deaths` and then in each row add up the number of elements that are not NA, not empty strings and not equal to `"present"`.  No packages are used.

```
Deaths <- data[grep("Death", names(data))]
rowSums(!is.na(Deaths) & Deaths != "" & Deaths != "present")
## A B C D 
## 0 1 1 2
```

An alternative to the last line of code that gives the same result would be to check each cell of each row for having a numeric and add up the successes in each row -- `apply` turns rows into columns so we use `colSums` to do that.

```
colSums(apply(Deaths, 1, grepl, pattern = "\\d"))
```

**Note:**  It's best to show the output of `dput(data)` in your question to unambiguously and reproducibly convey your input.  Without that there could be small differences between what you have and what answers assume so for purposes of reproducibility we used this as input (which corresponds to the original input data and sample output that was shown in the question before the was revised):

```
data <- 
structure(list(Birth1 = c(1990L, 1984L, 1985L, 1987L), Death1 = c("present", 
"1986", "1988", "1991"), Birth2 = c(NA, 1986L, 1988L, 1991L), 
    Death2 = c("", "present", "present", "1994"), Birth3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1996L), Death3 = c("", "", "", "present")), .Names = c("Birth1", 
"Death1", "Birth2", "Death2", "Birth3", "Death3"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

It looks like this:

```
> data
  Birth1  Death1 Birth2  Death2 Birth3  Death3
A   1990 present     NA             NA        
B   1984    1986   1986 present     NA        
C   1985    1988   1988 present     NA        
D   1987    1991   1991    1994   1996 present
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `Reduce` and `+`.  We loop through the columns with `lapply`, convert the elements to binary (`0/1`) by checking if the elements contain only number of not, and then with `Reduce` we sum up the corresponding elements of each row.

```
Reduce(`+`,lapply(data[grep('Death', names(data))], 
                grepl, pattern='^\\d+$'))
#[1] 0 1 1 2
```

NOTE: The example is taken from the `dput` output in @G. Grothendieck's post.